# TypeScript error when accessing propeties of object: "Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'string' .ts(2339)

Tags: typescript

I am passing an array of objects to my function.

Then I am looping through the array and trying to access the properties of each object.

But I am getting TypeScript errors saying this:

> Property 'docPath' does not exist on type 'string' .ts(2339)

and

> Property 'update' does not exist on type 'string' .ts(2339)

Here is my full function:

```TypeScript
export const useBatchUpdateDocTask = () => {
  return useTask(function* (
    signal,
    updatesArray: {
      docPath: string;
      update: {
        [x: string]: any;
      };
    }[]
  ) {
    const batch = writeBatch(db);
    for (const i in updatesArray) {
      const docRef = doc(db, i.docPath); // <-- ERROR HERE
      batch.update(docRef, i.update); // <-- ERROR HERE
    }
    yield batch.commit();
  });
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post more code? I get errors with the following symbols: useTask, signal, writeBatch, db, doc, in addition to the symbols you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I was using `for-in` which causes it to be of type `string`: `for (const i in updatesArray)`

But I should have used `for-of` which keeps the types intact: `for (const i of updatesArray)`